# Display both Leaflet Search Control and Legend on map created with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I'm having a strange issue.  For some reason I can't display the Leaflet Search plugin with the leaflet legend option.  I'm only able to show one are the other.  Whichever script is above is the feature that shows. Meaning if the Search Control script is place before the legend script, the Search Control is the one that is displayed and vice versa if the legend script is first.

I tried several ways to place both scripts in the code still can't seem to get both, Search and Legend to show together on the map. Can they work together, Search and legend, is the question I guess. Below is my script for the Search Control and Legend.  Both seems to work when it's on top of the other; or alone.

```
var markersLayer = new L.layerGroup();  //layer contain searched elements
  
    map.addLayer(markersLayer);

    var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
        position:'topright',        
        layer: markersLayer,
        initial: false,
        zoom: 16,
        hideMarkerOnCollapse: true,
        marker: { // custom L.Marker or false for hide
        icon: false, // custom L.Icon for maker location or false for hide
        animate: true, // animate a circle over location found
        circle: { // draw a circle in location found
          radius: 10,
          weight: 3,
          color: 'blue',
          stroke: true,
          fill: false,
          className: "circle"
        }
        }
    });

map.addControl( controlSearch, legend );
 
controlSearch.on("search:locationfound", function (e) {
    if (e.layer._popup) e.layer.openPopup();
  });

    ////////////populate map with markers from sample data
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        
        var title = locations[i].POC,
            loc = locations[i].SiteLocation,//position found
            //marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {title: title} );//se property searched
            marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng([locations[i].Latitude, locations[i].Longitude]), {title: title});

        marker.bindPopup('POC: '+ title + '<br>' + loc);

        var customIcon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: "icon/" + locations[i].Icon,//add graphic from CSV file
                iconSize: [40, 45], //size of the icon in pixels
                iconAnchor: [19, 35], //point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location (the center)
                popupAnchor: [0, -20], //point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
                className: locations[i].Class,
            });

        marker.setIcon(customIcon);
        markersLayer.addLayer(marker);
        
}

function getColor(d) {
    return d > 2 ? '#800026' :
           d > 1.5  ? '#BD0026' :
           d > 1.2  ? '#E31A1C' :
           d > 1.1  ? '#FC4E2A' :
           d > 1.5   ? '#FD8D3C' :
           d > 1.2   ? '#FEB24C' :
           d > 1.1   ? '#FED976' :
                      '#FFEDA0';
}
      

var legend = L.control({
  position: 'bottomright'
});

legend.onAdd = function(map) {
  var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
    grades = [0.2, 0.26, 0.32, 0.38, 0.44, 0.5, 0.56, 0.62, 0.68, 0.74, 0.8, 0.86, 0.92, 0.98, 1.04, 1.1],
    labels = [],
    from, to;

  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    from = grades[i];
    to = grades[i + 1];

    labels.push(
      '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '">[color]</i> ' +
      from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
  }

  div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
  return div;
};

// Do not forget to add your control to the map?
legend.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the controls individually instead.

Remove this line:

`map.addControl( controlSearch, legend );`

at the end of where you initiate the controls, add them to your map with "`.addTo(map)`":

`var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({ position:'topright', layer: markersLayer, initial: false, zoom: 16, hideMarkerOnCollapse: true, marker: { icon: false, animate: true, circle: {  radius: 10, weight: 3, color: 'blue', stroke: true, fill: false, className: "circle"} } })`**`.addTo(map);`**

`var legend = L.control({ position: 'bottomright' })`**`.addTo(map);`**

Comment: Hello Wilhelmb.  Thank you for your reply/solution.  I tried your suggestion be still got the same results basically. Only the Control Search will display and not the legend.  I looked at the developer tools and it's not showing any error.  I'm confused why these to controls won't display together.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this issue out.  It's not the best solution I guess but it worked.  I added the legend script in a function and triggered it with a timer.  I guessing both controls were trying to initiate at the same time and one was cancelling out the other.  By applying the timer, that delayed the loading of the legend allow both controls (search and legend) to display.  Below is the updated script with timer I put into place.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
display_legend(); 
}, 500);

function display_legend(){
function getColor(d) {
    return d > 2 ? '#800026' :
           d > 1.5  ? '#BD0026' :
           d > 1.2  ? '#E31A1C' :
           d > 1.1  ? '#FC4E2A' :
           d > 1.5   ? '#FD8D3C' :
           d > 1.2   ? '#FEB24C' :
           d > 1.1   ? '#FED976' :
                      '#FFEDA0';
}
      

var legend = L.control({
  position: 'bottomright'
});

legend.onAdd = function(map) {
  var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
    grades = [0.2, 0.26, 0.32, 0.38, 0.44, 0.5, 0.56, 0.62, 0.68, 0.74, 0.8, 0.86, 0.92, 0.98, 1.04, 1.1],
    labels = [],
    from, to;

  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    from = grades[i];
    to = grades[i + 1];

    labels.push(
      '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '">[color]</i> ' +
      from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
  }

  div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
  return div;
};

// Do not forget to add your control to the map?
legend.addTo(map);
}
```